# To extend the partition allotted for ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, filesystem

I am currently running windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04LTS, initially i allotted only 10GB partition to it,as it is not sufficient how can i extend my ubuntu partition without affecting windows.
file:///home/anupam/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202014-08-12%2014:06:48.png

Comment: Upload your screenshot to http://imgur.com/ and post the link to the image here.

Answer (score 0):

First boot into Windows and open Disk Management. From here shrink the Windows partition to free up space for Ubuntu.

Then boot from Ubuntu Live Media and use gParted to expand your Ubuntu partition into the new free space.

Although it's unlikely you'll encounter any problems, backing up important data on an external source is always a good idea when partitioning.